# Hölder semi-norm arbitrarily small?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I think I made a mistake in my proof, but I am not finding it.

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and consider a Cauchy sequence $\lbrace u_{n}\rbrace$ in the Holder space $\mathcal{C}^{k,\gamma}(\overline{U})$, $\gamma \in (0,1]$, for the usual Holder norm.

Let $v$ be the limit of $\lbrace u_{n} \rbrace$. Fix a number $\epsilon >0$. For each $x,y\in U$, with $x\neq y$, we can find $n$ and $m$ sufficiently large such that

$$ \frac{|u_{n}(x)-u_{m}(y)|}{|x-y|^{\gamma}} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{3} $$
$$ \frac{|v(x)-u_{n}(x)|}{|x-y|^{\gamma}} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{3} $$
$$ \frac{[v(y) - u_{m}(y)|}{|x-y|^\gamma } \leq \frac{\epsilon}{3} $$

With the triangular inequality, we therefore find that

$$ \frac{|v(x)-v(y)|}{|x-y|^{\gamma}} \leq \epsilon $$

Here, the bound $\epsilon$ is uniform with respect to $x$ and $y$, it's just a number we selected. We therefore have

$$ |v| = \sup_{x,y\in U, \ x\neq y} \frac{|v(x)-v(y)|}{|x-y|^{\gamma}} \leq \epsilon $$

which means, since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, that the Holder semi-norm of $v$ is arbitrarily small. If this argument it correct, then it would mean that the Holder semi-norm of any limit of Cauchy sequence in $C^{k,\gamma}(\overline{U})$ is zero, which I guess is probably false. But where is the error in my argument ?

Comment: Where are you getting your 3 inequalities from? It's certainly not by definition of Cauchyness and the Holder seminorm.

Comment: @peek-a-boo .Since $\lbrace u_{n} \rbrace$ is a Cauchy sequence in $C(\overline{U})$, then there exists $N>0$ such that for all $n,m\geq N$,  $\sup |u_{n}-u_{m}|\leq \frac{\epsilon}{3}|x-y|^{\gamma}$. Here $x$ and $y$ are fixed. for the two other inequalities, it just comes from the limit with the same $\epsilon-\delta$ argument.

Comment: Ah ok ! it's the sup of the function $u_{n}(t)-u_{m}(t)$, the same $t$. That's my error, thank's !